# When should comments be flagged/deleted on per-site metas?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation, per-site-meta, comment-flags

We all know [what comments are for -- and aren't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), but that guidance is, naturally, geared toward main sites, where we want to keep things clean and focused.  Meta, on the other hand, is a site's "second place", with some different rules and conventions.  For example, questions on main sites can be closed as primarily-opinion-based, but meta is all *about* opinions.  There's a "discussion" tag and such questions collect many opinions.  Meta is different.

Occasionally I see comment flags on metas and I'm never sure what to do with them.  Setting aside things that are blatantly offensive or spam (that's a no-brainer), is there such a thing as "too chatty" or a comment discussion that should be moved to chat *on meta*?  I am very conservative in deleting things on per-site metas (except on [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) posts, which like main should stay focused).

Are there any guidelines specific to per-site metas?

I'm specifying per-site metas and not MSE because MSE seems to have conventions that fall somewhere between "main site" and "per-site meta".  If the answer is the same for all metas then great, but I don't want to assume it'll be the same.

Comment: Personally, I hate deleting comments on meta. Meta is just a discussion place: The mandatory tag is literally [discussion] for any post. Unless something starts to get out of hand, I think I'd move it to a chatroom, and only after a gazillion comments that aren't getting anywhere.